# How to create a multidimensional array with phpQuery parsing HTML page?

Tags: parsing, phpquery

Here I have this code that works fine

```
include ("classes/phpQuery-onefile.php");
$url = "http://www.website.com";
$rawHTML = fetchRawData ( $url );
$parsedData = parseSpecificData ( $rawHTML );

//displayData ( $parsedData );
print '<pre>';
print_r($parsedData);
print '</pre>';

//our fetching function
function fetchRawData($url) {
    $ch = curl_init ();
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true ); //return the output as a variable
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true ); //fail if error encountered
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true ); //allow redirects
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10 ); //time out length

    $data = curl_exec ( $ch );
    if (! $data) {
        echo "<br />cURL error:<br/>\n";
        echo "#" . curl_errno ( $ch ) . "<br/>\n";
        echo curl_error ( $ch ) . "<br/>\n";
        echo "Detailed information:";
        var_dump ( curl_getinfo ( $ch ) );
        die ();
    }
    curl_close ( $ch );
    return $data;
}

//our parsing function
function parseSpecificData($data) {
    $parsedData = array ();
    phpQuery::newDocumentHTML ( $data );

    foreach ( pq ( ".box a" ) as $link ) {
        //print '<pre>';print_r($link);print'</pre>';
        $title = pq ( $link )->text ();
        if ($title) {
            $parsedData [] = array ("title" => $title,
                                            "href" => pq ( $link )->attr ( 'href' )
                                           );
        }
    }
    return $parsedData;
}
```

Here there is the content of the page that has to be parsed

```
<div class="box">
    <span class='name'>Name</span><br>
    <span class="address">Address</span><br>
    <a href='http://www.website.com'>www.website.com</a>
</div>
```

Here there is the output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => www.website.com
            [href]  => http://www.website.com
        )
)
```

My question is how to create an array with also the keys `name` and `address`.
Before ask I really search and try all the way, but there is something that I haven't understood in the phpQuery class.
Thanks for your help.
Alex